# Parallel.For not to use my main thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

In my application I want my main thread to be not used by anything else. I have to do some parallel processing that I would like to be done by different threads. For that I am using Parallel.For as follows

```
static void SomeMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Main Thread ID  before parallel loop ->>>>>>> {0} ", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Output ->>>>>>> {0} ", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    }); 
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Main Thread ID  after parallel loop ->>>>>>> {0} ", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
}
```

As you can see from the output main thread is using ThreadID 1 and some threads from Parallel.For are also using same thread.

```
Main Thread ID  before parallel loop ->>>>>>> 1
Output ->>>>>>> 1
Output ->>>>>>> 1
Output ->>>>>>> 3
Output ->>>>>>> 4
Output ->>>>>>> 4
Output ->>>>>>> 4
Output ->>>>>>> 4
Output ->>>>>>> 5
Output ->>>>>>> 3
Output ->>>>>>> 1
Main Thread ID  after parallel loop ->>>>>>> 1
```

Is there some way to make sure that anything in Parallel.For always run on separate thread so that main thread is always free.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there some way to make sure that anything in Parallel.For always run on separate thread so that main thread is always free.

`Parallel.For` will always block until everything is finished - so even if it *didn't* do anything on the original thread, the thread still wouldn't be "free".

If you want to keep the main thread "free" you might want to look into async and await - you could use `Task.Run` to start the 10 tasks in an async method, and then `await` the result of calling `Task.WhenAll`.

Alternatively, you could still use `Parallel.For` but do *that* in a task. For example:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => Parallel.For(0, 10, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Output ->>>>>>> {0} ", 
                      Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}));
```

You could then await *that* task. The "main thread" of the task will probably be used in the `Parallel.For` loop, but that's okay because it's still not your original main thread, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Does it mean that Parallel.For should not be called a UI thread? because in many case we don't want a UI thread to be blocked?

Comment: @johnsmith: Yes, exactly.